# How to cast from utc_time<seconds> to utc_time<days>

Tags: c++, casting, c++14, c++-chrono

I want to load utc_time< days > variable with year, month, day.
I do not know how to cast the result 'x' from date::utc_seconds to utc_time< days > and in general how to cast e.g. utc_time< milliseconds > to utc_time< days >...

```
auto x = to_utc_time(sys_days(year_month_day{ year{y}, month(m), day(d) }));
utc_time<days> utc_tp = ?x?; // now x => date::utc_seconds
```

**Solved:**
    utc_time< days > utc_tp = time_point_cast< days >(x);

time_point_cast casts from fine precision time_point to a coarser precision time_point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `time_point_cast<days>`, which truncates towards the epoch, there is also available:

- `floor<days>(x)` : truncate to the beginning of the current day.
- `ceil<days>(x)` : truncate to the beginning of the next day.
- `round<days>(x)` : truncate to the closest day boundary.

`time_point_cast<days>(x)` is equivalent to `floor<days>(x)` when `x` is after the 1970-01-01 epoch, and equivalent to `ceil<days>(x)` when `x` is prior to the 1970-01-01 epoch.